# How to create a Two-way ko.computed() array filter

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js, jquery-select2

I am trying to update 3 "Tags" fields ("ManagerTags","EmployeeTags","LocationTags") belonging to a Text object automatically.
Each Tags-field is a filtered array from a Tags=ko.observableArray().

This is the text object:

```
var Textbatch = function (data) {
    var self = this;

    self.TextbatchId = data.TextbatchId;
    self.Title = ko.observable(data.Title);
    self.Text = ko.observable(data.Text);
    self.TextTags = ko.observableArray();

    function createTypeComputed(tagType) {
        return ko.computed(function () {
            return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.TextTags(), function (item) {
                return item.Type() == tagType;
            });
        });
    }

    self.ManagerTags = createTypeComputed(0);
    self.EmployeeTags = createTypeComputed(1);
    self.LocationTags = createTypeComputed(2);

    self.removeTag = function (tagToRemove) {
        self.TextTags.remove(function (item) {
            return item.Id == tagToRemove.Id;
        });
    } 
}
```

The tag object looks like this:

```
var Tag = function(data){
    var self = this; 

    self.Id = data.Id;
    self.Name = ko.observable(data.Name);
    self.Type = ko.observable(data.Type);
    self.ParentTextId = data.TextId; 
}
```

I want the array "TestTags()" to be automatically updated with the filtered arrays (as a computed function maybe?). I.e. "ManagerTags()" (and "EmployeeTags()" and "LocationTags()") are two-way bound with "TextTags()" and not only one-way as the code above indicate.

See fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mnnEe/

Example: I want "Textbatch.ManagerTags()" to be a calculated subset of "Textbatch.TextTags()", where TagType=0.
But I want to edit and add tags through a select2-plugin:

```
<input data-bind="value: ManagerTags, select2: {tags: ManagerTags, tokenSeparators: [',', ' ']}"/>
```

How can I achieve this 2-way binding without this obvious circular reference?

Comment: Select2 and Knockout work well together as shown here - https://github.com/ivaynberg/select2/wiki/Knockout.js-Integration - What you are trying to do above and beyond that or why is not clear.

Comment: I have edited the text. Is it clearer now?

Answer (score 0):

I am having a hard time figuring out exactly what you are trying to do. But I think I have an idea. The only thing I can suggest is that your Textbatch object has an observable for the selected filter. Then subscribe to that observable. i.e add this to your Textbatch object.

```
self.selectedFilter = ko.observable(/*optionally set a default*/);
self.selectedFilter.subscribe(function(newValue){
switch(newValue){
    case 0:
    //Do your stuff
    break;
    case 1:
    //Do your stuff
    break;
    case 2:
    //Do your stuff
    break;
    default:
    break;
}
});
```

Now when you make and change to Textbatch.selectedFilter, you can update your entire object through the switch statement.